# Why come to the conclusion that f is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Here is the problem, but eventually reaches a conclusion, which I do not understand where the obtained

[image]

I know that a function is measurable if a domain is defined in measurable and meets certain Conditions by the given set as in the hypothesis and its equivalents are measurable

Can you help me please?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: it reaches the conclusion that f is measurable

Comment: Yes, but there are several arguments. Where _exactly_ are you stuck? Don't you understand why $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)<a\}$ being measurable for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is enough to ensure that $f$ is measurable?

Comment: yeah, that part is what I can not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $f$ is Borel-measurable given that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)<a\}$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is simply a consequence of the Borel sigma-algebra being generated by the sets $\{(-\infty,a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$, i.e.
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\{(-\infty,a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}).
$$
For a function $f$ to be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, meaning that
$$
f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\quad B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),
$$
it is enough to know that only
$$
f^{-1}((-\infty,a))\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\quad a\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

So let us show this last assertion, but in a more general setup (there is really no need to restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{R}$).

> Let $(X,\mathcal{E})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{F})$ be measurable spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a mapping. For a system of subsets $\mathcal{D}$ of $Y$ we define
>   $$
> f^{-1}(\mathcal{D})=\{f^{-1}(D)\mid D\in\mathcal{D}\}.
> $$
>   Then
>
> 1. For every system of subsets $\mathcal{D}$ of $Y$ we have
>      $$
>    f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{D}))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{D})).
>    $$
> 2. If $\mathcal{D}$ generates the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{D})=\mathcal{F}$), then $f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{F}$-measurable if only
>      $$
>    f^{-1}(D)\in\mathcal{E},\quad D\in\mathcal{D}.
>    $$

Let me just show 2: That $f^{-1}(D)\in\mathcal{E}$ for all $D\in\mathcal{D}$ means exactly that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{D})\subseteq \mathcal{E}$. This implies (using 1.) that
$$
\mathcal{E}\supseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{D})=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{D}))=f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}).
$$
But this exactly shows that $f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal{F}$-measurable.